# Trying to collect a list of ids from checkboxes to delete from my database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, partials

I'm creating an app (personal project) that'll help us schedule and record Nerf tournaments for a group I hang out with. I have `tournament` and `player` models. A tournament can have multiple players.

I want to be able to check multiple players and choose to delete them from the tournament. The thing is though is that all of my players are rendered in a nested partial. And my `tournament` partial has a form already inside of it.

Here is `_tournament.html.erb`:

```
<section class="panel" id="<%= dom_id(tournament) %>">
  <h1 class="heading">
    <%= tournament.name %>
  </h1>

  <ul>
    <%= render tournament.players %>
  </ul>

  <section class="add_players">
    <%= form_for [tournament, Player.new] do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_field :team %>
      </div>
      <%= f.submit "Add Player", class="button blue" %>
    <% end %>
  </section>

  <section class="delete_all">
    <button class="button red" type="button">Delete Players</button>
  </section>
</section>
```

and here is `_player.html.erb`:

```
<li id="<%= dom_id(player) %>">
  <div class="player">
    <%= check_box_tag "player_ids[]", player.id %>
    <span class="name"><%= player.name %></span> |
    <span class="team"><%= player.team %></span>
  </div>
</li>
```

I'm familiar with [Railscast #52](http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes) where he does a simpler example of this, but I can't figure out how to get all of those checked checkboxes in the tournament partial and use those ID's to delete those players from the tournament.

I've tried wrapping the `_tournament.html.erb` partial inside of a `form_tag` but it breaks some styling (and HTML doesn't really allow that as a standard.)

Any guidance or help would be great!

Comment: post your stack Trace!

Comment: @giridharan I don't really see how thats relevant as this code is conceptually broken.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is creating a form that posts to `/tournaments/:tournament_id/players` which makes sense if you are assigning the players one by one or creating a single player.

**It does not make sense at all if you are assigning multiple players to a tournament. Because you are actually changing the parent resource.**

In that case you should be sending a POST request to `/tournaments` (to create a tournament) or a PATCH request to `/tournaments/:id` (to modify an existing record).

```
<%= form_for tournament do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :player_ids, "Assign players" %>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :player_ids, Player.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit  %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
class TournamentsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  private
  def tournament_params
    params.require(:tournament)
          .permit(:foo, :bar, player_ids: [])
  end
end
```

If you want to be able to create multiple player records in a single request you should use [nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and [fields_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for).

To unassign all the players you can do a PATCH request to `/tournaments/:id` 
with an empty array as the value for `tournaments[:players_ids]`. You can do this with javascript by creating a handler that unchecks all the checkboxes and submits the form when the user clicks the button (or confirms it).

Or you could create a [custom `DELETE /tournaments/:tournament_id/players` route](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).

```
resources :tournaments do
  resources :players
  delete :players, on: :collection, action: :delete_all_players
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @max!

The form inside of `_tournament.html.erb` is used to create a single player at a time and attach it to the tournament, so using `/tournaments/:tournament_id/player` should be fine. 

I'll take a look at nested_attributes. I have a route right now that looks similar to your suggestion. Just mostly trying to find a way to collect a list of checkbox id's so I can pass them to ActiveRecord to handle / delete.

Comment: If the form creates a single player you don't need a checkbox in it. You should be handling it on the controller side by `@player = Tournament.find(params[:tournament_id]).players.new` as the tournament is passed through the path. That railscast is from 2007 and is pretty much completely useless today. And even at that is not really relevant for what you are doing.

Comment: The button at the bottom "Delete Players" (editing that now - should say "Delete Players", sorry) should allow me to delete a list of players that I've selected through checkboxes. So if there are 20 players listed, each should have their own checkbox, and clicking "Delete Players" should delete the _selected_ players from the tournament. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I would ask if you really need this as a separate feature. The normal checkbox lets you add / remove players from the tournament by just checking the boxes, which makes more sense from a UX perspective than having a separate input just to remove players.

Comment: You are most likely overcomplicating/overthinking a simple feature. [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Add the feature to delete all the players later if you actually need it.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here. The existing form to add players is literally just 2 input fields, you can enter whatever you want into them, on submit (clicking "Add Player") that new player gets added to the tournament; there's no link to any existing players ever, it's just a single "Player" that is a child of a "Tournament". The point of the checkboxes is to select multiple players and choose to delete them from the tournament if you want. Can be 1 player, can be all players. I know improvements can be made in terms of UI / UX but that's not what I'm trying to solve for right now.

Comment: I would really encourage you to just set it up as in the answer and try it. You're really overthinking it and mixing up the creation of records with just creating an association.

Comment: I'm not looking to delete all of the players every time though. And I'm unsure how to use nested attributes on the tournament model or form_for in either tournament or player partials to help in this scenario.

Comment: Its a simple rails app based on a scaffold that shows how you can both create nested records with nested attributes and associate exisiting records with checkboxes.